# Is a woman technically a niddah after childbirth?

Tags: halacha, pregnancy-birth, niddah, injury

I understand that a woman becomes a yoledet after childbirth, and that this condition has very similar laws to niddah. But is she also a niddah? I ask because as far as I understand, [niddah cannot be caused by dam makkah](http://www.jewishwomenshealth.org/article.php?article=73), or bleeding from trauma. Childbirth seems certainly in this category.

However, sources such as [this](http://www.jewishwomenshealth.org/article.php?article=20) suggest that she becomes both a niddah and a yoledet through childbirth. Is this true? Why?

Comment: Doesn't that site linked actually say she becomes yoledet which is similar to niddah?

Comment: @Yossi No; the second site says, "A woman enters the ritual status of niddah with certain signs of active labor. Following a vaginal delivery, she enters the additional ritual status of yoledet"

Comment: From the husband's point of view with respect to his wife, is there a practical difference between `niddah` and `yoledet`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nowadays a woman becomes a Niddah during childbirth, as we pasken (or: have taken upon as a Halacha) that most vaginal discharges cause Niddah.

Some very specific colors are except, but it needs training to discern them. 
Since childbirth includes a lot of blood, we assume that some of the blood may be Niddah-blood and since we cannot tell the bloods apart (as it would be absorbed in the childbirth blood) we simply assume she's a Niddah.

We also Pasken that if the entrance to the womb opens, then the woman is Niddah. This includes certain instruments used to check on fetal health, for example.

So to simplify things, we say that giving birth makes one a Niddah. But she's also a Yoledes and would not be allowed to go to the Mikva less than 14 days after giving birth to a daughter.

In rare cases of C-Section delivery without bleeding,  a woman could give birth and not be a Niddah, **if** it can be guaranteed that she had no troublesome vaginal discharge, before, during or after her birth.

The Shulchan Aruch in Yoreh De'ah in [סימן קצד - דיני יולדת ומפלת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_29.html#HtmpReportNum0011_L2) says that if there's no blood, then a C-Section delivery is permitted to her husband immediately, as she's not a Niddah and not a Yoledes.

> **יד:** יוֹצֵא דֹּפֶן, אִם לֹא יָצָא דָּם אֶלָּא דֶּרֶךְ דֹּפֶן, אִמּוֹ טְהוֹרָה מִלֵּדָה וּמִנִּדָּה וּמִזִּיבָה.‏

Comment: We hold (or have taken upon ourselves to treat her as if) she becomes a zavah, not a niddah. (If we're already being technical here about Yoledet as a separate kind of Tumah.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe you but wonder why the sites are saying she is a niddah. Do people use 'niddah' to mean 'zavah' these days?

Comment: @SAH Yes, people often use "Niddah" to mean "prohibited due to vaginal issues" even though there are roughly four distinct technical categories she could be in: Niddah, Zavah, Yoledet, Dam Tohar.

Comment: Danny, it might be worth noting about Dam Koshi.

Comment: @DoubleAA Weird, though, because the 2nd site I linked is so careful to distinguish between niddah and yoledet

Comment: @DoubleAA - i thought I covered that with _if it can be guaranteed that she had no troublesome vaginal discharge, before, during or after her birth_.

Comment: @DoubleAA Interestingly, this ( http://www.shemayisrael.co.il/dafyomi2/nidah/backgrnd/ni-in-11.htm ) (#4 line 28) suggests she is niddah and then dam tohar after childbirth -- but neither zavah nor yoledet.

Comment: @DoubleAA Also re: your first comment here--what of the idea that "a lying-in woman is unclean like a menstruating woman (in terms of uncleanness) (Lev. 12:2-5)" (here [http://www.jewfaq.org/613.htm] and "לאמר אשה כי תזריע וילדה זכר וטמאה שבעת ימים כימי נדת דותה תטמא" and "ואם נקבה תלד וטמאה שבעים כנדתה")